Next js App connected to Azure Application Insights
here I want to added my next js (typescript) app logs into Azure Application Insights.
I try to find good solution from doumentation, but it has poor guidence. this is what I followed for this:
https://medium.com/@nirbhayluthra/integrating-azure-application-insights-with-next-js-the-easy-way-afc83596afad
AppInsightService.tsx:
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
import { ReactPlugin } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js';

const defaultBrowserHistory = {
    url: "/",
    location: { pathname: "" },
    listen: () => { },
    state: {
        url: ""
    }
};

let browserHistory = defaultBrowserHistory;

if (typeof window !== undefined) {
    browserHistory = { ...browserHistory, ...window.history };
    browserHistory.location.pathname = browserHistory?.state?.url;
}

const reactPlugin = new ReactPlugin();
const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
    config: {
        instrumentationKey: "<my-key>",
        extensions: [reactPlugin],
        extensionConfig: {
            [reactPlugin.identifier]: { history: browserHistory },
        },
        enableAutoRouteTracking: true,
        disableTelemetry: false,
    }
});

if(typeof window !== undefined){
    appInsights.loadAppInsights();
}

export { reactPlugin, appInsights };

layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <AppInsightsContext.Provider value={reactPlugin}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </AppInsightsContext.Provider>
  );
}

dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^17.2.0",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-shims": "^3.0.1",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^3.2.1",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }

here this error occurs:

looking good solution for this problem

I can connect logs to Azure Application Insights using the following Next.js (TypeScript) code.
I ran the following commands to install the required packages:
npm install @microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js
npm install @microsoft/applicationinsights-web
npm install history

When I used your code, I also faced the same issue. The code below helps to resolve the issue.
components/AppInsightService.tsx:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
import { ReactPlugin } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const reactPlugin = new ReactPlugin();
let appInsights: ApplicationInsights | undefined;
const initializeAppInsights = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();
        appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
            config: {
                instrumentationKey: "<AppInsightsKey>",
                extensions: [reactPlugin],
                extensionConfig: {
                    [reactPlugin.identifier]: {
                        history: customHistory,
                    },
                },
                enableAutoRouteTracking: true,
                disableTelemetry: false,
            }
        });

        appInsights.loadAppInsights();
    }
};
const logMessageToAppInsights = (message: string) => {
    if (appInsights) {
        appInsights.trackTrace({ message });
    }
};
const AppInsightService: React.FC = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !appInsights) {
            initializeAppInsights();
        }
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        logMessageToAppInsights('AppInsightService component mounted');
    }, []);

    return null;
};
export { reactPlugin, AppInsightService };

components/layout.tsx:
import { AppInsightsContext } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js';
import { reactPlugin } from './AppInsightService';
const Layout: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <AppInsightsContext.Provider value={reactPlugin}>
            {children}
        </AppInsightsContext.Provider>
    );
}
export default Layout;

Pages/hello.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import RootLayout from '../components/layout';
import { AppInsightService } from '../components/AppInsightService';
const HelloPage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, Next.js!</h1>
      <p>This is the Hello page.</p>
      <RootLayout>
            <AppInsightService />
        </RootLayout>
    </div>
  );
};
export default HelloPage;

package.json:
{
  "name": "my-nextjs-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^17.2.0",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^3.2.1",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

Using the above code, I successfully ran the application with the following command:
npm run dev

Output:

Below are the logs of the Next.js project in Azure Application Insights.

